# Any DvdFab/DvdShrink comparable program for Mac?

Tags: software-recommendation, dvd

I want to rip a dvd (and/or blu-ray) to an ISO, but remove some of the features on the disk (i.e. menus, extra features).  DvdFab and DvdShrink for Windows allow users to do this.  Any similar programs for Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, it's called Mac DVD Ripper Pro, it works great on my Snow Leopard MacBook Pro, and it's Lion-compatible according to the RoaringApps website. It costs $19.95 at the moment, and the free demo works on 5 DVDs, website is here:

http://www.macdvdripperpro.com/

FYI, the RoaringApps Lion app compatibility table is here:

http://roaringapps.com/apps:table/

Comment: I like it better than Ripit since I can burn "main movie only", but unfortunately, they only let me choose one section/chapter of the disk in this mode.  I'll contact the manufacturer to request multiple video selections (first movie I tried was split over a few sections, so my "main movie" was simply the first half of the movie).  Additionally, the output is ".dvdmedia", and not "iso", so an additional conversion will be needed possibly (if i really NEED iso -- TBD)

Comment: There is an app called DVD2One that gives you this kind of control over sections, subtitles, etc., but it cannot remove the copy-protection from the DVD. So you could use Mac DVD Ripper Pro to get the movie onto your HDD, then DVD2One to create the .iso you want from those files. Free trial exists, app costs $40 (ouch!). I own this software but haven't had occasion to use it for a long time. (I normally use HandBrake to make AppleTV-compatible files, and only resort to the DMRP app as an intermediate step when Handbrake has trouble with copy protection on a particular DVD.)

Answer (score 3):

[RipIt](http://thelittleappfactory.com/ripit/) is the best I've seen. You can try it free, it is paid software with a novel guarantee. If you can't rip a title, they will buy that title and fix their software for you.

Comment: RipIt is nice (and that additional benefit you mention is really nice), but I can only rip the full disk (or use the "beta compress" feature (uses Handbrake), which I don't think allows for the picking and choosing of disk features).

Comment: RipIt would work just fine as a first step. For the 2nd step, DVD2One could be used on the ripped files to selectively remove content.

Answer (score 1):

How about [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/)?

Comment: Handbrake is too slow in my experience.  I like DVDShrink and DVDFab on windows because i get my ripped disk at 100% quality within 10-15 minutes.